# How to point specific to ip in android tablet?

Tags: android, dns, hosts

I am accessing my local server by using DNS. For this I have made changes into my etc/hosts of my PC. However I am not able to access it through my andoid devices. Is there any way to do it. Please suggest the method. I have also installed windows server 2012.

I have created a virtual host in the server and I need to access the virtual host in My andriod device also

Comment: what is your mean please add some more details what you want exactly..

Comment: want to point xyz.com to specific ip in android tablet

Comment: it is android application or some thing else are you connected by cable or not with tablat or not..??

Comment: @amitsharma I am connected via wi-fi.

Comment: if you are connected by wifi then it can not possible it is just because of your system derives are not server where your data can not transfer at that time your data will transfer by cable if you want to communicate his data to his system..

Comment: just connect by cable then your data will store in your system server ... or local system server..

Answer (score 1):

You can use ADB pull/push, assuming your device is rooted.

HowToGeek has a pretty simple [step-by-step tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/140576/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-on-android-and-block-web-sites/)

Comment: Sorry the device is not rooted